# How do i duplicate an element in 2d vector c++ and put it next to the original element

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > fog { { 'a', 'b', 'c'  },
                                    { 'f', 'g', 'a' } };
```

Above vector should turn in to fog

```
{ { 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'c', 'c'  }, { 'f', 'f','g', 'g', 'a' 'a' } };
```

I already tried using the `insert()` method of `std::vector` but it keeps on giving me segmentation faults.

Comment: It probably would be more efficient to just recreate a new vector in a loop that simply does two `push_back` calls for each letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> fog {
        { 'a', 'b', 'c' },
        { 'f', 'g', 'a' }
    };

    fog[0].reserve(fog[0].size() * 2); // make sure the vector won't have to grow
    fog[1].reserve(fog[1].size() * 2); // during the next loops *)

    for (auto &v : fog) {
        for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it += 2)
            it = v.insert(it + 1, *it);
    }
}
```

*) cause it would invalidate all iterators if the vector would have to grow beyond it's capacity.

Using the return value of `insert()` it can be done without `reserve()`:

```
for (auto &v : fog) {
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        it = v.insert(it + 1, *it);
}
```

Comment: Do we really need for reserving?

Comment: you are right, since my code uses the return value of `insert()` to update `it` there is no iterator left that could become invalid. Without that and doing `it += 2` in the `for`-statement it is necessary.

Comment: @Swordfish Thank you for your help. I was using two regular integer for loops and it was not working. I think segmentation default was caused because of adding unnecessary counter variable to the insert position. I makes sense now. Thank you.